# .NET Compact Framework 2.0 Dialog lost focus

Tags: c#, .net, forms, dialog, compact-framework

I have a form that opens a another as a dialog with

```
form.ShowDialog()
```

But I have a problem that I think is being cause by the new dialog losing focus.

Sometimes the original form just remains and the new dialog never opens.

I think it might be that in an attempt to open the new dialog via a button, I press somewhere on the initial form again before the new dialog opens. Could that be that giving focus to the initial form is just overlapping the new dialog?

I don't know how to check this, and it doesn't always happen.

Answer (score 1):

> I think it might be that in an attempt to open the new dialog via a button, I press somewhere on the initial form again before the new dialog opens.

Try something like this:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  button1.Enabled = false;
  using (Form2 form = new Form2())
  {
    form.ShowDialog();
  }
  button1.Enabled = true;
}
```

That would prevent your button from being clicked twice.

Comment: Thanks, I'll give that a try once I get a chance.  But wouldn't the user still be able to click somewhere else on the form to give it focus?

Comment: @TheFabledOne this shouldn't matter, and no you can't do that.